# Spivak, Ch. 20, Problem 19: Understanding Lagrange's Method for proving Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

The following is an interesting problem from Chapter 20, entitled "Approximation by Polynomial Functions", of Spivak's *Calculus* .

My question is about how to interpret the problem and its solution in a way that provides some intuition and insight. In particular, in deriving Taylor's theorem's expression for the remainder term, a particular function is used in the argument. One of my questions below is if different, interesting results would be obtained using a different function in the argument.

Here is the problem (note that though the problem statement is kind of long, the problem itself is relatively straightforward, and the main difficulty is interpretation of the steps).

> 19. Lagrange's method for proving Taylor's Theorem used the following device.
>
> We consider a fixed number $x$ and write
>
> $$f(x)=f(t)+f'(t)(x-t)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n+S(t)\tag{*}$$
>
> for $S(t)=R_{n,t}(x)$. The notation is a tip-off that we are going to
> consider the right side as giving the value of some function for a
> given $t$, and then write down the fact the derivative of this
> function is $0$, since it equals the constant function whose value is
> always $f(x)$.
>
> (a) Show that
>
> $$\begin{align*} 0=&f'(t)+\left [-f'(t)+\frac{f''(t)}{1!}(x-t)\right ]
>  \\ & +\left [-\frac{f''(t)}{1!}(x-t) +\frac{f^{(3)}}{2!}(x-t)^2\right
>  ] \\ &\ +(...) \\ & +\left [
>  \frac{-f^{(n)}(t)}{(n-1)!}(x-t)^{n-1}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n\right
>  ] \end{align*}\tag{1}$$
>
> and notice that everything collapses to
>
> $$S'(t)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n$$
>
> Noting that
>
> $$S(x)=R_{n,x}(x)=0$$
>
> $$S(a)=R_{n,a}(x)$$
>
> apply the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem to the functions $S$ and
> $h(t)=(x-t)^{n+1}$ on $[a,x]$ to obtain the Lagrange form of the
> remainder (Lagrange actually handled this part of the argument
> differently).
>
> (b) Similarly, apply the regular Mean Value Theorem to $S$ to obtain
> the strange hybrid formula
>
> $$R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n(x-a)$$
>
> This is called the Cauchy form of the remainder.

Here is my solution

$(a)$ The expression $(1)$ is simply the result of differentiating $(*)$ relative to $t$. After cancelling terms in $(*)$ we reach

$$0=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n+S'(t)$$

$$\implies S'(t)=-\frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n\tag{2}$$

> **Note:** In the context of this problem we don't know what Taylor's theorem is yet. $(*)$ is just a polynomial plus an unknown function
> $S(t)$. With the benefit of knowledge of Taylor's theorem, we can see
> that $(*)$ is essentially saying that the value $f(x)$ can be
> expressed as a Taylor polynomial about a variable $t$ plus a remainder
> term. For each choice of $t$, the first $n+1$ right-hand side terms
> potentially change, and the final term $S(t)$ changes as well so as to
> keep the sum of all right-hand side terms constant.
>
> The expression for $S'(t)$ tells us how $S(t)$ changes when we change
> $t$ in this way.

Moving on, note that in $(*)$ if we set $t=x$ we have

$$f(x)=f(x)+S(x) \implies S(x)=R_{n,x}(x)=0$$

and

$$S(a)=R_{n,a}(x)$$

> **Note:** The use of the notation $R_{n,a}$ is simply to indicate what we know after the fact, that $S(a)$ represents a well-studied entity we call remainder, ie the difference
> between $f(x)$ and a polynomial.

Now we define a function $h(t)=(x-t)^{n+1}$.

Then $h'(t)=-(n+1)(x-t)^n$.

Recall the Cauchy MVT:

> **Cauchy MVT** If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$
> then there is some $x\in (a,b)$ such that
>
> $$[f(b)-f(a)g'(x)=[g(b)-g(a)]f'(x)$$

Apply this MVT to $S(t)$ and $h(t)$ on $[a,x]$.

There exists a $c\in (a,x)$ such that

$$[h(x)-h(a)]S'(c)=[S(x)-S(a)]h'(c)$$

$$(x-a)^{n+1}\cdot \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n=R_{n,a}(x)(n+1)(x-c)^n\tag{3}$$

$$R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}\tag{4}$$

> **Note:** This latter part is the one I have my doubts about. $a$ was simply introduced by the problem without further ado. The way I
> understand the roles played by $x$, $t$, $a$, and $c$ is the
> following.
>
> $x$ is fixed.
>
> Given $x$, we can choose any $t$ to satisfy $(*)$. $t$ is thus just a
> variable.
>
> Now specify some other fixed value $a$, and a function $h(t)$. Then
> the CMVT says that given $x$ and $a$ there is a third value $c\in (a,x)$ such that $(3)$ and
> ultimately $(4)$ are true.
> Now, $(4)$ looks like it expresses a function $R_{n,a}$ of $x$, but $x$ is
> fixed. It seems like $(4)$ means that the term $S(a)$, which as noted previously represents the difference between $f(x)$ for a fixed $x$ and a polynomial in $t$ evaluated at $a$ (and that we know is a remainder) can be expressed in terms of some unknown value $c$.

**Question:** Could we interpret $(4)$ as a function of both variables $x$ and $a$? That is, does $(4)$ tell us not only what happens to the remainder when we vary $a$, but also when we vary $x$?

**Question:** It seems like the special and famous expression we find for the remainder comes from a relationship between the remainder function $S$ and a specific function $h$. If we choose $h$ differently do we reach other interesting/notable/famous results?

**Now let's do part (b).**

As noted previously, we have

$$S(x)=0$$

$$S(a)=R_{n,a}(x)$$

Apply MVT to $S$ the interval $[a,x]$.

There exists some $c\in (a,x)$ such that

$$\frac{S(x)-S(a)}{x-a}=S'(c)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n$$

where we have used the result in $(2)$ for $S'(t)$.

Thus

$$S(a)=R_{n,a}(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n(x-a)$$